# rosjava external sources

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm developing a rosjava package in eclipse, and I need  to use some java classes that I am developing in another non-ros java eclipse project. Does anybody knows how I could configure these dependencies properly in my rosjava project?
I've tried with the rosjava-src tag in the manifest and giving an absolute path for the location of my external java sources dependencies, but that path doesn't seem to be correctly resolved. I do prefer not to add these classes to a jar file because they're still under development.

Thank you for any idea

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12852/rosjava-external-sources/) by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you Juan Antonio and Damon for your ideas. I've finally committed to maintain these dependencies for other Java sources in the .project eclipse file, it is easier since I develop only from within eclipse, and the debugging works really nicely.

---

Originally posted by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) with karma: 202 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0